# How to display private videos using Dailymotion SDK on iOS?

Tags: ios, dailymotion-api

I've been trying to use the DailyMotion iOS SDK, but the videos I need to display are all private, something I can't change. Currently, I receive the following message:

> Content not Available. The video you requested cannot be displayed on this website. [xxx] has limited its access to Dailymotion.

I tried using my API key, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
self.dailyMotionPlayer = [[DMPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideo:self.externalLink params:self.parameters];
```

What should I use in this parameter dictionary in order to use my API key and secret? Tried using `syndication`, with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the Dailymotion SDK for iOS does not enable to play private videos, so it is not possible to do so.

The SDKs may evolve and additionnal feature can be added in the future, so stay tuned on our twitter feed [@DailymotionAPI](https://twitter.com/DailymotionAPI).

FYI, the `syndication` parameter is used to track the revenues generated when you are a partner.

Comment: Even if I send the auth token along with the video request?